# Update document in a collection with different document types, but same partition key

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a cosmos db document collection which contains different kinds of documents, but sharing same partition keys. Is there a way to update document with same partition key, but different document type  via C#? In all the examples I have seen, deleting/updating a document requires a unique partition key/document uri. But, in my case there are 3 documents with same partition key.

Below is a collection(borrowed from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/modeling-data) with 2 types of documents partitioned by 'bookId'.

I would like to know if there is a way to update/delete documents using partition key and a type/other criteria.

Example1: Update document with bookId: "b1", type: "review" and id: "r1"

Example2: Delete all documents with bookId: "b1"

```
Book documents:
{
    "id": "b1",
    "name": "Azure Cosmos DB 101",
    "bookId": "b1",
    "type": "book"
}

Review documents:
{
    "id": "r1",
    "content": "This book is awesome",
    "bookId": "b1",
    "type": "review"
},
{
    "id": "r2",
    "content": "Best book ever!",
    "bookId": "b1",
    "type": "review"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cosmos does not support set-based insert/update/delete operations. You must call these operations individually from your client or you can write a stored procedure and pass in whatever is needed to find the relevant data but you're still going to call those operations individually, just server side.

Examples:

[Replace an item](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Samples/Usage/ItemManagement/Program.cs#L420)

[Delete an item](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Samples/Usage/ItemManagement/Program.cs#L509)

[Write stored procedures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-write-stored-procedures-triggers-udfs)

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Is there a best practice for reading multiple types of documents in a single call in C#? Say I wanted to fetch book details (including name) as well as all reviews for bookId:1. Would it be better to query all documents with bookId:1 and then in C#, do some kind of typecast based on the type? Or have 2 separate reads?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how you would do it. Send a query in one operation to get all the data, then iterate through the result set, checking the type property and using a switch or some conditional to then hydrate a POCO that represents the hierarchical shape of your data, then returning to the user, web page, etc.